# How to publish a PDF file stored in Google Drive on a Google Sites?

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites, google-drive-sharing

I published a Google Sites webpage for anybody to access it with links to PDF files (presentations for my classes).

Unfortunately, anybody who tries to download the PDF files needs special permission from me. This happened because the PDF files are stored in my Google Drive account.

I'd like to allow anybody to download it without any special permissions from me. I want to share these files with the world, I don't want to bother sending
share invitations around. So far, I did not find any way around this. 
I could try to insert the file directly from the drive option on the side panel in Google Sites, but that doesn't seem to work inside a text box.
Creating a subpage is an option, but it seems awkward.
The instructions I've seen on the web seem outdated.

I think there's some simple solution I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- go to your Drive - **https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive**
- locate that PDF file
- right-click it and select **Share**
- click on **Advanced**
- click on **Change...**
- select one of the **On - ...** options
- under **Access: Anyone (no sign-in required)** select your **Can ...** preference
- hit the **<kbd>Save</kbd>** button
- make sure that last checkbox is **un-ticked**
- click on the **<kbd>Done</kbd>** button

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The PDF needs to have "link sharing" turned on. The simplest way to do this on a computer is to select the file in [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/), then click on the share icon: [image: share icon], and click on "Get shareable link":

[image: Sharing dialogue box]

Alternatively, on Android, find the file in the Google Drive app, tap the three dots, then tap on the "Link sharing off" option, to turn link sharing on:

[image: Android]